# repaint(); not Updating

Tags: java, swing, repaint

I'm new to java, and as a challenge I'm following some tutorials on how to create a small game. I've managed to make a nice keyboard input reader but sadly I don't know why my `repaint();` isn't working... The point is to change the ints `Py` and `Px`, they are responsible in changing the position of the player!

This is the class `f2`, a JPanel that is added to a Jframe in another file.

````
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class f2 extends JPanel implements Runnable{
    

    keys keyh = new keys();
    Thread gameThreadMain;

    //background color  
    Color bg2 = new Color(81,89,98);
    Color txt1 = new Color(237,237,237);

    //width control
    final int w = 700, h = 700; 


    int wp = 64, hp = 64;

    //spawn cords
    //
    int spawn1x = (w / 2) - (wp / 2);
    int spawn1y = (h / 2) - (hp / 2);

    //Player Speed
    int Px = spawn1x;
    int Py = spawn1y;
    int Ps = 4;

    //FPS
    int fps = 60;

    public f2(){

/*      this.addKet*/
        this.setBackground(bg2);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w,h));
        this.setDoubleBuffered(true);

        /*this.setLayout();*/
    }

    public void startGameThreadMain(){
        gameThreadMain = new Thread(this);
        gameThreadMain.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){

            double drawInterval = 1000000000/fps; 
            double nextDrawTime = System.nanoTime() + drawInterval;

        while(gameThreadMain != null){
            

            update();

            repaint();
            /*System.out.print("check");*/
            

            try{
                double remainingTime = nextDrawTime - System.nanoTime();
                remainingTime = remainingTime / 1000000;

                if (remainingTime < 0) {
                    remainingTime = 0;
                }

                Thread.sleep((long) remainingTime);

                nextDrawTime += drawInterval;

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void update(){
        //Keyboard

        
        if(keyh.UpPressed == true) {
            Py -= Ps;
        }
        else if(keyh.DownPressed == true) {
            Py += Ps;
        }
        else if(keyh.LeftPressed == true) {
            Px -= Ps;
        }
        else if(keyh.RightPressed == true) {
            Px += Ps;
        }else{
            //
        }
        
    }


    //player painter (this is the part where the 'repaint();' isn't working
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D player = (Graphics2D)g;

        player.setColor(txt1);
        player.fillRect(Px,Py,wp,hp);


        System.out.println("repainted");
    }

}``` 

//Thanks for reading!
````

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please see: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616)

Comment: `startGameThreadMain` is never called.  Having said that, I just want to congratulate you, if there is a wrong way to do something, you've just about achieved. See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html); [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html); [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html); [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

`startGameThreadMain` is never called.

Swing is not thread AND is single threaded.  You should never update the UI, or some state the UI depends on, from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details and [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for one possible solution.

You should also be aware of:

- [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html)
- [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

For example...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class Player {
        private int x;
        private int y;

        private Color backgroundColor = new Color(237, 237, 237);

        private Shape shape;

        public Player(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.shape = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }

        public void setLocation(int x, int y) {
            setX(x);
            setY(y);
        }

        public void setX(int x) {
            this.x = x;
        }

        public void setY(int y) {
            this.y = y;
        }

        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public int getY() {
            return y;
        }

        public int getWidth() {
            return 64;
        }

        public int getHeight() {
            return 64;
        }

        public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(backgroundColor);
            g2d.translate(getX(), getY());
            g2d.fill(shape);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

    public enum Movement {
        UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT;
    }

    public interface MovementObserver {
        public void movementDidActiviated(Object source, Movement movement);
        public void movementWasDeactiviated(Object source, Movement movement);
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {
        private Timer timer;

        private Player player;

        private Set<Movement> movements = new HashSet<>();

        public TestPane() {
            player = new Player(0, 0);

            int spawnY = (getPreferredSize().width - player.getWidth()) / 2;
            int spawnX = (getPreferredSize().height - player.getHeight()) / 2;
            player.setLocation(spawnX, spawnY);
            setBackground(new Color(81, 89, 98));
            timer = new Timer(15, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (movements.contains(Movement.UP)) {
                        player.setY(player.getY() - 1);
                    } else if (movements.contains(Movement.DOWN)) {
                        player.setY(player.getY() + 1);
                    }
                    if (movements.contains(Movement.LEFT)) {
                        player.setX(player.getX() - 1);
                    } else if (movements.contains(Movement.RIGHT)) {
                        player.setX(player.getX() + 1);
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });

            MovementObserver observer = new MovementObserver() {
                @Override
                public void movementDidActiviated(Object source, Movement movement) {
                    movements.add(movement);
                }

                @Override
                public void movementWasDeactiviated(Object source, Movement movement) {
                    movements.remove(movement);
                }                
            };

            InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap am = getActionMap();

            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, false), "Up.pressed");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0, false), "Down.pressed");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, false), "Left.pressed");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, false), "Right.pressed");

            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, true), "Up.released");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0, true), "Down.released");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, true), "Left.released");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, true), "Right.released");

            am.put("Up.pressed", new MovementAction(Movement.UP, observer, true));
            am.put("Down.pressed", new MovementAction(Movement.DOWN, observer, true));
            am.put("Left.pressed", new MovementAction(Movement.LEFT, observer, true));
            am.put("Right.pressed", new MovementAction(Movement.RIGHT, observer, true));

            am.put("Up.released", new MovementAction(Movement.UP, observer, false));
            am.put("Down.released", new MovementAction(Movement.DOWN, observer, false));
            am.put("Left.released", new MovementAction(Movement.LEFT, observer, false));
            am.put("Right.released", new MovementAction(Movement.RIGHT, observer, false));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(700, 700);
        }

        @Override
        public void addNotify() {
            super.addNotify();
            if (timer == null) {
                return;
            }
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void removeNotify() {
            super.removeNotify();
            if (timer == null) {
                return;
            }
            timer.stop();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (player == null) {
                return;
            }
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            player.paint(g2d);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

    public class MovementAction extends AbstractAction {
        private Movement movement;
        private MovementObserver observer;
        private boolean activate;

        public MovementAction(Movement movement, MovementObserver observer, boolean active) {
            this.movement = movement;
            this.observer = observer;
            this.activate = active;
        }

        public Movement getMovement() {
            return movement;
        }

        public MovementObserver getObserver() {
            return observer;
        }

        public boolean doesActivate() {
            return activate;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (doesActivate()) {
                getObserver().movementDidActiviated(this, getMovement());
            } else {
                getObserver().movementWasDeactiviated(this, getMovement());
            }
        }

    }
}
```